# Override environment variable when running on Jenkins

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, phpunit, jenkins, phing

I'm testing a Zend Framework application using PHPUnit and Jenkins. I need to override the `APPLICATION_ENV` environment variable which is access using PHP's `getenv` in the PHPUnit `bootstrap.php` file:

```
<?php

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

... use APPLICATION_ENV to pick database, configuration, etc. ...
```

I have two environments: `testing` (for local machines) and `testing-ci` (for Jenkins machine). How can I set the variable to `testing-ci` when it runs in Jenkins? Is there any way to set it in `build.xml` for Ant or Phing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1:** Add the environment variables to Jenkins.

Open either the global or project-specific configuration page depending on your needs and scan down for the **Environment variables** section. Check the checkbox and use the **Add** button to add key/value pairs.

These will be passed by Jenkins to your Ant build script.

**Step 2:** Load them into Ant.

Near the top of your Ant `build.xml` script, load all environment variables with an `env` prefix so they don't interfere with other properties.

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

Now all imported variables will be available using the `env` prefix, e.g. `${env.HOME}`.

**Step 3:** Pass them to PHPUnit.

Assuming you're using the `<exec>` task to run PHPUnit, you can pass each needed variable to it using the `<env>` child element.

```
<exec taskname="test" executable="phpunit">
    <env key="APPLICATION_ENV" value="${env.APPLICATION_ENV}"/>
    ...
</exec>
```

**Note:** You might want to try just the first step to see if Ant will pass the environment variables along to executed child processes, but I think the other two steps are good for making it clear what is required to other developers.

Comment: Simpler and more elegant, I'll grant you that. But mine works via phpunit itself without an "ant" dependency.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith - Rafael specifically asked about Jenkins and Ant (`build.xml`) or Phing.

Answer (score 0):

OK.

Here's what you do...

First, create a new file called bootstrap.php.

Next, in boostrap.php, put the following code:

```
if (!empty($argv) && 
    ($key = array_search('--environment', $argv)) !== FALSE)
{
    $env = $argv[$key + 1];
    putenv('APPLICATION_ENV=' . $env);
}
```

Load the bootstrap.php into your testsuite or (even better) phpunit.xml.

Finally, via your CI build config, or via the console or wherever, execute your unit tests like `phpunit UnitTest.php --environment dev`.

You're good to go.

Comment: Sorry I don't know if you understood me but I already have bootstrap.php and phpunit.xml, nowdays It works locally on my machine database but when goes to jenkins it's another database password. I need a solution to change the env variable in jenkins configuration or in the build.xml so that won't break my local testing and will work on jenkins.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.  I'm editing my post now with an updated solution.

Comment: It would be a solution however in my case I'm running a suite test case configured by xml (phpunit --configuration ./tests/phpunit.xml). PHPUnit doesn't accept receive --environment but anyway thanks :)

Comment: Yes it does. Man. Do some research before you dismiss my answer. http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/appendixes.configuration.html See the PHP INI settings. You'd want <env name="env" value="dev"/>.

Comment: I know it, I was using it before but this solution needed 2 config xml (phpunit.xml and phpunit-ci.xml) it works but I need to keep two xml files otherwise it will apply the environment to my local machine and jenkins.